# Electronic Forms and Workflow

Tags: forms, workflow

I work in a company that have a lot of Standard Operation Procedures that wich to automate. There are a lot of forms, complex workflow, and business rules. These forms should be accessible to company members through Intranet and the Internet.

We tried to find ready made software with no luck?

What is the best way to implement these forms? Should we use a ready made software? or implement our own -we have in-house developers with VB.Net and C# experience mainly building Win Forms applications- ? What companies usually use or do in this case?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information about the workflow to make a good judgement of that. However you say it is complex. Therefore I think something custom made would be best. Because you have many forms you want something with transactions as well I guess.

Comment: Thank you. We are trying to create our own; however its very time consuming. And the real problem is making forms web enabled. We tried ASP.Net and MVC but it seems quite hard to create user friendly forms without JavaScript, AJAX, JQuery .. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

We use [LiquidOffice](http://www.cardiff.com/products/liquidoffice/) which is a pretty full featured product.  It is Java based but we have gotten it integrated into SharePoint just fine.  We use it both internally and externally with very complex workflows and routing.

Other options include InfoPath and SharePoint itself.  Trying to roll this out yourselves will probably cost way more with less desirable results than just going with a 3rd party product.

Comment: Thank you. We tried InfoPath -it is good- but we can't use the forms through the Internet - there are alot of problems using certificates and trust issues. We tried Sharepoint and it is a pain to install, adminster, and the built in workflow is limited, if we need to customize it we need to work alot with WF!

Answer (score 0):

What's your budget and scale?  Oracle, IBM, and SAP are the biggest vendors of that kind of software, but it's definitely not cheap.   It will scale to pretty much any size though.

Comment: I think you are talking about IBM Lotus Forms, and it out of our budget. For Oracle, and SAP can you please tell what are there products for e-forms and workflow?